# What does the sentence "there is an in-flow negative vertical margin vertical margin such that ..." in CSS SPEC?

Tags: css

This sentence is too difficult to understand. I don't quite understand what it means. Can anyone provide some examples?

> But in CSS 2.2, if, within the block formatting context, there is an in-flow negative vertical margin such that the float's position is above the position it would be at were all such negative margins set to zero, the position of the float is undefined.

[9.5.1 Positioning the float: the 'float' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-float)

Comment: I understand `"Note: this means that floats with zero outer height or negative outer height do not shorten line boxes."`, but `negative margins set to zero`??? It's weird...So I want someone to explain this sentence completely. :)

Comment: If a floated element is preceded by a (not floated or positioned) div with `margin-bottom:-10px`, that margin would be an in-flow negative vertical margin. The browser could position the float vertically below the div as if that margin was -10px or 0px and either position would be conforming. However, I suspect it's just a historic thing. CSS 2 was first written when Internet Explorer and Netscape Navigator ruled the roost and the note was probably to keep both sides happy. I suspect all modern browsers use -10px so demonstrating the undefinedness likely isn't possible.

Comment: @Alohci emm, I don't understand what you said about the case of `margin-bottom:-10px`.. Can you provide an example, pls?

Comment: What don't you understand? That margins can be negative, or what the expected behaviour of a negative margin is?

Comment: @Alohci It's a little embarrassing. I'm not a native English speaker. What I don't understand is the expected situation caused by what you said about 'margin-bottom: -10px'. yeah, expected behaviour.  I think that's what you [mean](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/images/longdesc/float2p-desc.html)

Comment: @Alohci In addition, you say this is a historical reason. Does this mean that it is not so important?

Comment: That's correct, I suspect it's not important, because it has no effect in modern browsers.